# How to re-position game object to the left side of the screen when it goes off the right side of the screen?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a portrait game and I'm trying to achieve something like the offscreen movement logic of the games Doodle Jump or Radical.

How do I re-position a game object to the left side of the screen when it goes off the right side of the screen and vice versa without being dependent of the screen size/aspect ratio?

Here's a snippet of code that I have right now:

```
void CheckBounds()
     {
         if (this.transform.position.x < -3.2f)
         {
             this.transform.position = new Vector3(3.2f, this.transform.position.y, this.transform.position.z);
         }

         if (this.transform.position.x > 3.2f)
         {
             this.transform.position = new Vector3(-3.2f, this.transform.position.y, this.transform.position.z);
         }
     }

 void MovePlayer()
 {
             if (isFacingLeft)
         {
             this.transform.position -= new Vector3(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
         }
         else
         {
             this.transform.position += new Vector3(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
         }
 }
```

Now this works but it's a dirty solution. As you can see I hard coded the bounds when the object goes offscreen which is +/- 3.2f.

This works perfectly on 16:9 aspect ratio devices but not on other aspect ratio devices.

How do I detect the screen edges to make this work regardless of the screen aspect ratio?

Thanks

Comment: Check this tutorial as it doesn't use any objects outside of the screen's bounds to check for its position. https://youtu.be/VAmlb913-jc

Answer (score 1):

I've made 2 assets to solve this problem:

Objects Edges 2D & Camera Edges

they allow you to simply write:

```
if( player.GetLeftPosition().x > myCamera.GetRightPosition(10))

     player.MoveRightPosition(myCamera.GetLeftPosition(10));
```

- they work with any game object scale, sprite pivot, collider size or offset

**Assets Links:**

**Object Edges 2D:** http://u3d.as/wkF

**Camera Edges:** http://u3d.as/xxB

Hope you it helps you & saves your time.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to place two empty objects marking left and right limits.

You can check in Update (or just when character moves to improve performance) if character is outside of game bounds (on the left of left limit, or in the right of right limit) and fix it position accordingly:

Something like:

```
if(character.position.x < leftLimit.position.x - MARGIN) {
    character.position.x = rightLimit.position.x - MARGIN;
}

if(character.position.x > rightLimit.position.x + MARGIN) {
    character.position.x = leftLimit.position.x + MARGIN;
}
```

MARGIN adds a small tolerance to avoid flickering.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand your approach but how do I place the 2 empty objects to be at the left/right edge of the screen without being dependent on the device's screen size? You know, without eyeballing it.  Still new to Unity, sorry.

Comment: I'm used to game programming in SpriteKit. There I simply use 0 to get the left edge and size.width to get the right edge. Is there something similar in Unity?

Comment: Maybe using `Camera` to get world points. Have a look to this: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/537081/how-to-make-the-player-stay-within-screen-in-a-sim.html

Answer (score 0):

This script is used for screen wrapping an object within the screens bounds (viewport). All you do is place this script onto your gameobject and it will do the rest. No need for colliders on the outside of your camera, it's just place and play. You can also set the public bool's to determine whether you want your gameobject to wrap on the width, height or both. Video tutorial here: https://youtu.be/VAmlb913-jc

Head over to [this website](http://www.SavalishUnityTutorials.com) for a bunch of Unity3D tutorials.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ScreenWrap : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public bool wrapWidth = true;
    public bool wrapHeight = true;

    private Renderer _renderer;
    private Transform _transform;
    private Camera _camera;
    private Vector2 _viewportPosition;
    private bool isWrappingWidth;
    private bool isWrappingHeight;
    private Vector2 _newPosition;

    void Start () 
    {
        _renderer = GetComponent <Renderer> ();
        _transform = transform;
        _camera = Camera.main;
        _viewportPosition = Vector2.zero;
        isWrappingWidth = false;
        isWrappingHeight = false;
        _newPosition = _transform.position;
    }

    void LateUpdate () 
    {
        Wrap ();
    }

    private void Wrap ()
    {
        bool isVisible = IsBeingRendered ();

        if (isVisible)
        {
            isWrappingWidth = false;
            isWrappingHeight = false;
        }

        _newPosition = _transform.position;
        _viewportPosition = _camera.WorldToViewportPoint (_newPosition);

        if (wrapWidth)
        {
            if (!isWrappingWidth)
            {
                if (_viewportPosition.x > 1)
                {
                    _newPosition.x = _camera.ViewportToWorldPoint (Vector2.zero).x;
                    isWrappingWidth = true;
                }
                else if (_viewportPosition.x < 0)
                {
                    _newPosition.x = _camera.ViewportToWorldPoint (Vector2.one).x;
                    isWrappingWidth = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (wrapHeight)
        {
            if (!isWrappingHeight)
            {
                if (_viewportPosition.y > 1)
                {
                    _newPosition.y = _camera.ViewportToWorldPoint (Vector2.zero).y;
                    isWrappingHeight = true;
                }
                else if (_viewportPosition.y < 0)
                {
                    _newPosition.y = _camera.ViewportToWorldPoint (Vector2.one).y;
                    isWrappingHeight = true;
                }
            }
        }

        _transform.position = _newPosition;
    } 

    private bool IsBeingRendered ()
    {
        if (_renderer.isVisible)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```